# Fedora: issues configuring git config (Github)

Tags: git, fedora

I am having problems with set my git account default identity and connect with Visual studio Code.
I followed the instructions below:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git add*
```

Then I got something like

`error: open("XXXX.pub"): Permission denied error: unable to index file 'XXXX.pub' fatal: adding files failed`

I understand that there is some issue with my ssh key.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not a problem with `git config`, not with ssh keys — it's a problem with `git add *` that cannot add file `XXXX.pub` due to permission problem.

Comment: Thank you, so I will see what my IT department says!

Comment: Where are you running `git add *`? And is there a space between `add` and `*`? That command would only make sense in a Git sandbox. I'm guessing you're trying to turn your home directory into a sandbox to save your configuration, because `XXXX.pub` is a typical filename in your `~/.ssh` folder. If so, that's not a very good idea, you probably want to reconsider how you want to save your config files.

Comment: GitHub and GitLab are not relevant here. Git is (and Fedora is slightly relevant), but this is almost certainly a basic usage mistake in that you're probably creating your Git repository in the wrong place and adding your entire home directory.